i have issues with configuration of odoo 17 along with pycharm
i've tried to configure an external odoo.conf file in conf folder under hospital management system when i tried to run i've got this error:
Usage: odoo-bin server [options]
odoo-bin server: error: unrecognized parameters: 'management system/conf/odoo.conf'
this is my conf/odoo.conf file:
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoonew17
db_password = psswrd
addons_path = /path/to/my/hospital maagement system/odoo-17.0/addons
default_productivity_apps = True
http_port = 8069

and this is my debian/odoo.conf file:
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
;addons_path = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons
default_productivity_apps = True

script : /path/to/hospital management system/odoo-17.0/odoo-bin
parameter: -c /path/to/hospital management system/conf/odoo.conf
working directory:/path/to/hospital management system.
i've tried by prefixing odoo-bin, odoo, odoo-bin server, odoo server with parameter.

From the error message, I suspect the issue might be that your parameter is being read as "-c /path/to/hospital" and "management system...". According to JetBrains the solution might simply be to remember to wrap your parameters in doublequotes if they contain spaces.
